How do i compare 2 dates with specific format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") in groovy script
I have to compare 2 dates
date 1 - "2024-06-18T10:08:39.1271797"
date 2 - "2024-06-18T10:08:39.124669"
I have to test compare both dates in ready api and make sure they both are equal. I dont need the last seconds.1271797 from date 1 and .124669 from date 2.
I have tried lots of options but failed. Can anyone please help me to trim those fields in groovy script for this please.

Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

@sumita-bali you can "accept" the answer as it addresses your question very well. There should be a button for that near the upvote buttons.

So if the seconds are for example 39.013892 and 39.981738, more than 0.9 seconds apart, they are OK, but 38.963992 and 39.012323, less than 0.1 seconds apart, are not??

Assuming you have a standard install, or groovy-dateutil module on your classpath:
def fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"
assert Date.parse(fmt, "2024-06-18T10:08:39.1271797")
    == Date.parse(fmt, "2024-06-18T10:08:39.124669")

If you know the format will never change, you can just compare strings:
assert "2024-06-18T10:08:39.1271797".split(/\./)[0] ==
       "2024-06-18T10:08:39.124669".split(/\./)[0]


The first part of the answer is missing removing the milliseconds, no?

The format contains no milliseconds, so none will be added to the date.

Ah that's true! Great.

java.time
In March 2014, Java 8 introduced the modern, java.time date-time API which supplanted the error-prone legacy java.util date-time API. Any new code should use the java.time API*.
Solution using modern date-time API
Since your date-time strings are in the default format used by LocalDateTime#parse, you do not need to specify any DateTimeFormatter explicitly.
Having parsed these strings into a LocalDateTime, you can truncate them to the seconds.
Demo:
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;


date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2024-06-18T10:08:39.1271797").truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
date2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2024-06-18T10:08:39.124669").truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
println date1 == date2

Output:
true

Online Demo
Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from Trail: Date Time.

* If you are receiving an instance of java.util.Date, convert it tojava.time.Instant, using Date#toInstant and derive other date-time classes of java.time from it as per your requirement.

